DOT1x port authentication drops when CA restarts
We have dot1x configured on some ports on our C9300s. Lately we have been seeing when we restart the CA server for patching, as it restarts an loses connection to the switch our ports with dot1x drop out because they aren't authenticated until the server comes back on and the ports are shut down and turned back on. I am thinking it is the timer set on the port to reauthenticate the port.
Per this information the default timeout for 802.1X and MAB is 90 seconds which is about how long the connection remains connected. So what I am thinking is I should add this line to my config
dot1x timeout reauth-period 7200

The reauthentication is not dictated through our RADIUS so it runs on the switch default. Is this the correct control to allow it to run for about 2 hours without reauthentication? Should I lower it to 30 minutes or an hour for a secure connection?

Using the command dot1x timeout reauth-period 7200 will cause the connected endpoint to reauthenticate in 2 hours.  This is the correct command to achieve this effect.
You can control the reauthentication from your AAA server if you use the command dot1x timeout reauth-period server.  The reauth timer can be pushed from your AAA server via RADIUS attributes.
I would not lower the authentication timer for a secure connection. Not only will the endpoint reauthenticate every two hours, but the authentication process will also be required if the endpoint is disconnected.
